# IIS 7 Authenication

Tags: iis

I have created a folder for a site that i would like authentication for. I am able to this with windows authenication. I would like to be able to this without having to create windows accounts. I have tried doing forms authentication but it gives me "This feature has been locked and is read only" when I try to enable it at the folder level. Is there a way I can enable it, and if not what would be the best way to authenticate withough windows accounts?